# Setting up a 2nd Springboot application to use a @Autowired repository @Component from App 1 caused incorrect loading and REST requests broke

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, autowired, spring-data-rest

I have setup 2 `Spring Boot` applications.  I am trying to `@Autowire` the repository from `Application 1` in `Application 2`.

Both of these applications will be using REST to communicate back and forth.  When I ran `application 2` alone without the `@Autowire` of the repository for `Application 1` I could correctly communicate with `http://localhost:8082/runTestExecution` via the `@RestController` `HomeController` class without an issue.

When I setup the `@Autowire` and `@ComponentScan({"com.miw.mcb.server.repositories"})` so that I have access to the repositories of `Application 1`, `Application 2` no longer functions correctly.

I am unable to reach the `@RestController` at `http://localhost:8082/runTestExecution`.

I also had a class which implemented `CommandLineRunner` which would run when I started up `Spring Boot` and this no longer runs either.

```
@Component
public class InitialRunner implements CommandLineRunner
```

1. Is this a issue because `Application 1` also has a main class which loads `@SpringBootApplication`?
2. Can anyone suggest what is going wrong?

Below I have outlined my steps I took to add the jar of `Application 1` and `@Autowired` class to `Application 2`

Here are the steps I took:

1. Setup maven to have the new library dependency and add it to the maven library `mvn:install`
2. Add Autowired bean to the `HomeController` class:

   ```
   @RestController
   public class HomeController {

       @Autowired
       TestSuiteRepository repo;

       @RequestMapping(value = "/")
       public String index() {
           return "index";
       }

       @RequestMapping("runTestExecution")
       public String runTestExecution(@RequestParam(value = "testExecutionID", required = true) String testExecutionID) {

           return "Good";
       }
   }
   ```

Main class

```
  @SpringBootApplication
  public class AdbService {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AdbService.class, args);
  }
```

`TestResultRepository` class

```
package com.miw.mcb.server.repositories;

@Component
public interface TestResultRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TestResult, Long> {
  }
```

3. Add `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan`, only supply the comment scan for the repositories package of the JAR file

`Application 2` main class

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan({"com.miw.mcb.server.repositories"})
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class AdbService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(AdbService.class, args);
    }
    }
```

`Application 1` Config Class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.miw.mcb.server.repositories"})
public class AppConfig {

}
```

`Application 1` Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Prior to adding the `@ComponentScan` I got the following stack trace:

> 2016-04-14 13:29:56 - Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.miw.mcb.server.repositories.TestSuiteRepository
>   com.miw.mcb.adbservice.HomeController.repo; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.miw.mcb.server.repositories.TestSuiteRepository] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
>     at com.miw.mcb.adbservice.AdbService.main(AdbService.java:38)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Prior to adding the @ComponentScan I got the following stack trace:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `@EnableJpaRepositories` instead of `@ComponentScan` for JpaRepositories:

```
@Configuration
//@ComponentScan({"com.miw.mcb.server.repositories"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.miw.mcb.server.repositories")
@SpringBootApplication
public class AdbService {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(AdbService.class, args);
}
}
```

Comment: Yes this worked adding the '@EnableJpaRepositories'  but a new error emerged because the Entity is not added for TestResult which is used by the JPA repository.  

New stack trace:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.miw.mcb.server.entities.TestResult'

I then needed to load the Entities with '@EntitiyScan' to look for all domain entries which are used by the JPA repositories 
 '@EntityScan("com.miw.mcb.server.entities")'